# UICollectionViewDelegate in RxCocoa

Tags: rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I write an extension for UICollectionView which will listen the  delegate's
shouldHighlightItemAt method,but it don't call.

```
public var shouldHighlightItem: ControlEvent<IndexPath> {

    let source = self.delegate.methodInvoked(#selector(UICollectionViewDelegate.collectionView(_:shouldHighlightItemAt:)))
        .map { a in
            return try self.castOrThrow(IndexPath.self, a[1])
    }

    return ControlEvent(events: source)
}
```

}

how to write an extension for UICollectionView of rx shouldHighlightItemAt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `methodInvoked(_:)` with a delegate method that has a non void return type.

`collectionView(_:shouldHighlightItemAt:)` expects you to return a `Bool` value. So you cannot use `methodInvoked(_:)`.

If you have a look at the implementation of `methodInvoked(_:)` it gives you an explanation why this does not work:

> Delegate methods that have non `void` return value can't be observed
>   directly using this method
>            because:
>
> - those methods are not intended to be used as a notification mechanism, but as a behavior customization mechanism
> - there is no sensible automatic way to determine a default return value

There is however a suggestion how you could achieve what you are trying to do:

> In case observing of delegate methods that have return type is
>   required, it can be done by
>            manually installing a `PublishSubject` or `BehaviorSubject` and implementing delegate method.

In your case it would work like this:

**In `RxCollectionViewDelegateProxy` you add the 'PublishSubject' and implement the `UICollectionViewDelegate` method:**

```
let shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPathSubject = PublishSubject<IndexPath>

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPathSubject.on(.next(indexPath))
    return self._forwardToDelegate?.collectionView(collectionView, shouldHighlightItemAt: indexPath) ?? true // default value
}
```

**In your UICollectionView RxExtension you can expose the desired Observable like this:**

```
public var property: Observable<IndexPath> {
    let proxy = RxCollectionViewDelegateProxy.proxy(for: base)
    return proxy.shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPathSubject.asObservable()
}
```

I have not tested this, I merely took it from the RxCocoa source code and modified it to fit your needs. So in theory this should work, but you might have to tweak it a little bit ;-)